# Creating dynamic xpath for selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

Could you please help me to create XPATH. I want to delete the item with dynamic url. Here is DOM structure. 'beacon name', 'Major: 22 ' are not changed. Only href is changed.

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-small">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title">beacon name</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 preview-data"> UUID: E4504AB5-309C-41BF-BAC4-C384A9EBE57A </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 preview-data"> Major: 22 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 preview-data"> Minor: 33 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="action-btns pull-right">
     <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="/beacons/114/edit?back_to=%2Fbeacons">Edit</a>
     <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/beacons/114?back_to=%2Fbeacons">Delete</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

XPath I tried:

```
//a[contains('beacon name',/'Delete')]
```

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: //a[contains('beacon name',/'Delete')]

Comment: this does not help too: //a[contains('beacon name') and text()='Delete']"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match `"Delete"` button by `"Major: 22"`, try

```
//div[normalize-space()="Major: 22"]/following-sibling::div//a[text()="Delete"]
```

if by `"beacon name"`:

```
//h3[.="beacon name"]/following::a[text()="Delete"]
```

You also can try to use `href` attribute:

```
//a[@href="/beacons/114?back_to=%2Fbeacons"]
```

Comment: Oh, cool! Thank you a lot! First and second work fine! The third one is not good because  this url is changed every time when I delete the item

Comment: You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) in case it solved your issue

Comment: Thank you! Done!